# How can I install/view the grub file that a recent upgrade was providing but I accidentally ignored?

Tags: apt, grub2, upgrade

A recent `apt upgrade` wanted to overwrite my system's grub file that I had manually modified, but I accidentally kept my own modified version. How can I view the version that was going to overwrite my modified grub file or re-run the installation of the associated package to overwrite my grub file?

Comment: To re-run the installation of a package, do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall package`.

Comment: I don't know which package wanted to overwrite my grub file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also rejected the edit to my modified `/etc/default/grub` after examining it in the dialog

I found the proposed version cached in `/var/lib/ucf/cache`

You can see it:

```
less /var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub
```

you can see what's different:

```
diff /var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub /etc/default/grub
```

To directly **overwrite** your current `/etc/default/grub` with the proposed version, first making a backup copy of the current one:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub-backup
sudo mv /var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub /etc/default/grub
```

Or to edit your current `etc/default/grub` to make changes yourself

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

If you make a change, don't forget to run

```
sudo update-grub
```